# C - My writes to a file are lost

Tags: c, file, file-io, fopen

I've been given a task to write some lines (which are normally sent to stdin) to a .txt file of my choice.

Using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
FILE * henry;

henry = fopen ("henry.txt", "w");

fprintf(henry, "This is some test text to be printed to a file!");
}
```

This correctly outputs to a file, as it should. However, when simply adding this to the below piece of code, it removes all current text inside the file I want to write to, but somehow doesn't actually write to it! The below is the code that I have so far, but it's missing other files. But from just looking at it, does anyone know why it doesn't output to my specified file?

```
//critical_example2.c
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "se207_sems.h"

int main(int argc, char argv[]){
  FILE * henry;
  henry = fopen ("text.txt", "w");
  fprintf(henry, "This is some test text to be printed to a file!");
  //Use our source file as the "key"
  int id=se207_semget("critical_example2.c",1);

  int pid=fork();  
  if(pid ){
    //P1 = Process 1 is Henry.
    while(1){
      se207_wait(id); printf("There's a hole in the bucket, dear Liza, dear Liza,\n");
      rsleep();       printf("There's a hole in the bucket, dear Liza, a hole.\n");

      se207_signal(id);

      se207_wait(id); printf("With what shall I fix it, dear Liza, dear Liza?\n");
      rsleep();       printf("With what shall I fix it, dear Liza, with what?\n");

      se207_signal(id);

      se207_wait(id); printf("The straw is too long, dear Liza, dear Liza,\n");
      rsleep();       printf("The straw is too long, dear Liza, too long.\n");

      se207_signal(id);

      se207_wait(id); printf("With what shall I cut it, dear Liza, dear Liza?\n");
      rsleep();       printf("With what shall I cut it, dear Liza, with what?\n");

      se207_signal(id);

    }
  }else{
    //P2 = Process 2 is Liza
    while(1){
      se207_wait(id); fprintf(stderr, "Then fix it, dear Henry, dear Henry, dear Henry,\n");
      rsleep();       fprintf(stderr, "Then fix it, dear Henry, dear Henry, fix it.\n");
      //fprintf added to all of Liza's lines, with the location stderr being specified for output.
      se207_signal(id);

      se207_wait(id); fprintf(stderr, "With straw, dear Henry, dear Henry, dear Henry,\n");
      rsleep();       fprintf(stderr, "With straw, dear Henry, dear Henry, with straw.\n");

      se207_signal(id);

      se207_wait(id); fprintf(stderr, "Then cut it, dear Henry, dear Henry, dear Henry,\n");
      rsleep();       fprintf(stderr, "Then cut it, dear Henry, dear Henry, cut it.\n");

      se207_signal(id);

      se207_wait(id); fprintf(stderr, "With an axe, dear Henry, dear Henry, dear Henry,\n");
      rsleep();       fprintf(stderr, "With an axe, dear Henry, dear Henry, an axe.\n");

      se207_signal(id);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i can't find fclose()

Comment: You never close for flush the file, and the buffered output remains stored in your process's memory.

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE]. Use [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) & [fclose](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose). Read the [documentation of C standard IO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call either [`fflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html):

```
fflush(henry);
```

or [`fclose()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html):

```
fclose(henry);
```

on your `FILE*` variable after you're done writing. Otherwise, like @AndrewHenie suggests, data might stay in your process' buffers and not actually be written before your program terminates.

**Important**: Your code does not check `henry` is non-`NULL` - which it might be, on failure! Similarly, you should check the return value of `fflush()` and `fclose()`.